# Create an uber jar for Dataflow and Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to create an uber jar containing my pipeline, Dataflow and Apache Beam using Maven, is there an example available that I could look at?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [example Maven project](https://github.com/lukecwik/incubator-beam/tree/dataflow_uber_jar) containing the Apache Beam examples, GCP I/O and Dataflow.

The instructions in README.md should help get you up and running the Leaderboard[2] example and point to the relevant Maven shade plugin instructions.